# Excel connected to SSAS 2012 Cube shows all data in filtered record

Tags: ssas, cube

I am very new to SSAS, I am facing a problem into SSAs cube. Suppose I have connected to SSAS cube through excel, there I am filtering on attribute1(month) of dimension1(date). Then I am taking another attribute1(transaction) from dimension2(account) , in that case when I am selecting drop down arrow this filter I should only get those transactions in the list which comes under the month which I have selected in filter one. But I am getting all the transactions irrespective of month. Is it a SSAs cube limitation??

Comment: No. The filtering will happen when you add these fields in excel as rows, columns. In the filter you will see all the values. If you are expecting filters to magically refresh then no, that doesn't happen!

Comment: Thanks Sourav, yes you are right in row label's value I could see filtered data. But I want the same into filter list. Because it is becoming inconvenient when you want to filter a record and you are seeing thousands of records in the list. Doesn't this excel refreshes itself because in normal pivot of excel this type of filter works :(

Comment: I guess excel filters are static. I have no idea how to make that refresh or probably that's not possible.

Comment: There isn't a way to change the fact that a filter connected to SSAS source shows all values and isn't filtered based upon other filters.  You can use slicers in place of filters to help with this scenario. http://blogs.office.com/2009/09/25/interacting-with-slicers/

Comment: Can I achieve same via creating roles.. Means if I have roles country wise then one country's users will see only data of that country while selecting filter condition from the dimension, which contains data of all countries?